# How to generate an API key for Mysql PHP webservice?

Tags: php, mysql-workbench

I need to generate an API key for my webservice.
Can anyone suggest idea for that?
Users who use my webservice should have an API key.

Comment: generate a key based on some random string and store it in an access table.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider implementing OAuth2's client_credentials.

I am suggesting OAuth2 so that at least you are not home cooking yet another solution.

Try looking at the posts and urls below for reference.

https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Client-Credentials-flow

[Understanding OAuth2 Client credentials flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140020/understanding-oauth2-client-credentials-flow)

[Securing a REST API written in PHP with OAuth2 client credentials flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368504/securing-a-rest-api-written-in-php-with-oauth2-client-credentials-flow)

If all you care about is the exact mechanics involved in generating the key, consult this post that is doing in C# but the concept is language agnostic.

[how to generate OAuth client identifier and client secret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947437/how-to-generate-oauth-client-identifier-and-client-secret)