# How to generate client-id & client-secret in spring-boot and store in database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I know questions similar to this already exist on stackoverflow. When I went through them, it didn't solved the problem I'm looking for.

I've a **spring-boot web service** as `Oaut2ClientManagement`, in which I've creating an API which will basically register a new client.
When new company is getting registered, the `companyId`(it is predefined in some `company_details` table, yes the company is added in list but not registered to access APIs) is sent so based on that I've to generate `client-id` & `client-secret` which I'll store in `CLIENT_KEY_MANAGEMENT` table. Based on this I write a java code to generating `accessToken`.

So my question here is how can I generate **client-id** & **client-secret** based on `companyId` I've received in request ? I've went through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23671977/1995161). But is there any pre-defined way in `spring-boot oauth` which can do this job ? As next step is to generate access token based on it.

I also went through oAuth [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/). But, in this the `client-id` & `client-secret` are stored in properties file not in Database/other source. Also seems like it's single pair.

It will be great if someone can guide me to achieve above scenario using `spring-boot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `JdbcClientDetailsService` for this specific purpose.

You need to define the following table in your database

```
create table oauth_client_details (
  client_id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
  resource_ids VARCHAR(256),
  client_secret VARCHAR(256),
  scope VARCHAR(256),
  authorized_grant_types VARCHAR(256),
  web_server_redirect_uri VARCHAR(256),
  authorities VARCHAR(256),
  access_token_validity INTEGER,
  refresh_token_validity INTEGER,
  additional_information VARCHAR(4096),
  autoapprove VARCHAR(256)
);
```

and configure your Oauth2 authorization server as following

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

}
```

And finally you can inject `JdbcClientDetailsService` bean in the location you are registering a `companyId`.

```
@Autowired
JdbcClientDetailsService jdbcClientDetailsService;

...
BaseClientDetails clientDetails = new BaseClientDetails(companyId, resourceIds, scopes, grantTypes, authorities);
clientDetails.setClientSecret("generatedpassword");
jdbcClientDetailsService.addClientDetails(clientDetails);
```

Finally you can login using those client credentials.

**UPDATE**

If you want your passwords to be hashed you can set a PasswordEncoder as below.

```
clients.jdbc(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
```

`BaseClientDetails` is available in package `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client`.

The client secret will not be generated by the service. You need to generate it and set it to `BaseClientDetails`.

Comment: The `generatedpassword` will be converted/hashed before saving it to the table `oauth_client_details` or it will be saved as it is ? `BaseClientDetails` will be a custom Object, right ? In this structure when `client_secret` will be generated which I can use to pass it to other table ?

Comment: Thank you so much. This make sense to me now. I'll play around with what you've provided.

Comment: I've one question here, the `companyId` we are passing to constructor is nothing but `client-id` correct ?

Comment: Yes, your companyId can be the client id as long as companyId is unique

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginConfigurer;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    public SecurityConfiguration(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        this.clientRegistrationRepository = clientRegistrationRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }
}
```

need this code for springboot 3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).